# Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 do-release-upgrade: "No new release found"

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have a problem while upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04. We have few thousand devices on Ubuntu 14.04 that need to be upgraded to 18.04. I have tried to upgrade to  16.04 first. But when I try `do-release-upgrade` I get "No new release found".

What I'm trying is below.

```sh
## edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades, change never as lts
sed -i "/Prompt=/c\Prompt=lts" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

## to make dpkg continue non-interactively
echo "force-confdef" >> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.conf
echo "force-confold" >> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.conf

# to upgrade non-interactively 
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

## update, upgrade and do-release-upgrade
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
```

Comment: Unless you're paying Canonical for extended maintenance, 14.04 went EOL a long time ago. It's a bit too late at this point to talk about upgrading and you should devise a plan to reinstall the OS.  If you *are* paying Canonical for support, you should contact them.

Comment: thanks @Nmath for your feedback. We have close to 10,000 devices on ubuntu 14.04 all  over USA. We want to upgrade to 18.04 for security reasons. We would like to remotely upgrade due to cost of replacing devices.  We are not paying for support.

Comment: Yikes! Neglect from your IT dept has put your organization in a very deep hole... 14.04 has been EOL for so long, it's unlikely that upgrade to 16.04 will go well. You can't just skip to 18.04. I'm afraid that you are going to have to reinstall a supported operating system from scratch on each of these devices. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure: Don't neglect regular maintenance and you would not find yourself in this kind of impossible situation. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: 20.04 has just had it's first point release (20.04.1) and is a stable candidate for installation.  I suggest installing 20.04.1 on your devices.  Your organization will need to have a plan to upgrade these devices **before** April 2025 when 20.04 will reach EOL.

Comment: Thank you @Nmath. I have contacted Canonical support on the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/)